# Shell script that replaces itself in the history with a different command

Tags: bash, zsh

I am looking for a bash/zsh (I guess they behave the same here?) script that replaces itself in the history when run. E.g., think of a search script that searches a command for me. When I then press the up arrow key afterwards, I want to have the command I searched there instead of the script I ran.

For example, how would I replace the command in the history with `hello world`? Let's say the script is called `magic.sh`. Expected behavior:

- User executes `./magic.sh`
- User presses up arrow
- `hello world` is displayed instead of `./magic.sh`
- (Also, the user can search for `hello world` with Ctrl+R and will find it; but I guess that's for free once the history is replaced)

Comment: Where did `hello world` come from, the output of `magic.sh`?

Comment: Please focus a question on either bash or zsh. If you want answers for both, ask two questions. Imagine that you get to your question one excellent answer for bash and another one for zsh - which one would you "accept" (i.e. put the green checkmark on)? Stackoverflow allows you to accept only one answer.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but the [zshaddhistory-hook](https://stephencharlesweiss.com/zsh-hooks) could do the job in zsh. There is a concrete example in the linked page which nearly does what you are aiming for (it modifies the actual string which is to be placed into the history). I really wonder why on earth you want to use this feature for ....

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, you can use the `history` command to push a new entry onto the history list. The `history` command itself is not added to the history list first.

```
$ history -s hello world
```

In `zsh`, you can do the same with the `print` command (though the `print` command *will* be added to the history list).

```
% print -s hello world
```

Comment: I think that we can avoid `print` being added to the history in zsh, if we write the command with a leading space (`' print ...'`) and turn on `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` in the shell.

Comment: True; I think both shells have ways of deleting commands from the history list as well, but it's simpler if you can avoid adding a command in the first place.

Comment: (I didn't want to complicate the answer much beyond what it already is, since I'm not sure it's exactly what the OP is looking for.)

Comment: The man page says about this setting: _Note that  the  command
 lingers  in  the  internal  history until the next command is entered before it vanishes  If you want to make it  vanish right away without entering another command, type a space and press return._, I don't think we can do better than that in zsh.